# Sending charts automatically as pdf in email

Tags: .net, pdf, ssis, ssas, ssrs-2012

I am currently in a state of doubt whether I am doing the things in the right way. Basically, I have a task where data which is stored in a normalised db in MSSQL needs to be queried for so as to be displayed on different charts. These charts then needs to be converted in a custom PDF and are to be sent as an email attachment automatically.

What I am doing: I am currently querying the data using LINQ, modifying the data to make them in JSON structure in the server side. Then in the client side, I am using AJAX to consume the JSON data and displaying it using google charts. Then, I am using jsPDF to generate the PDF by clicking a button.

The solution I currently have works fine, however it is slightly manual, in the sense that I need to click a button to generate the PDF and send email. Do you recommend a better workflow to get the data, produce them as charts (even if these are done in server side) and send them as an email in one automatic process? I never used SSIS, SSRS and SSAS, so these might be good to look into.

Any feedback on this please? Would you require more details on this to make it more clear, please let me know :)

Technologies used: .NET, MVC, AJAX, JSON, Google chart, jsPDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely do this with an SSRS subscription.

Comment: Ok, however if I need to do some calculations aswell such as calculating data for quarters, can logic such as this be included before generating the SSRS report? - sorry if this is a newbie question.

Comment: Sounds like a simple enough calculation (aggregation) that it can be done in SSRS, and actually, SSRS allows you to write custom .net code for it, so whatever you need is probably possible.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer :)